# System.OutOfMemoryException when using method to escape XML

Tags: c#, escaping, out-of-memory

I have a C# console app that reads in data from a Data Table and parses the data into XML that is sent out to an external API. When parsing the data I have been using a method to escape five different characters within the XML.

```
private static string EscapeXml(string rawText)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> xmlCharactersToEscape = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    xmlCharactersToEscape.Add("&", "&amp;");
    xmlCharactersToEscape.Add("\"", "&quot;");
    xmlCharactersToEscape.Add("'", "&apos;");
    xmlCharactersToEscape.Add("<", "&lt;");
    xmlCharactersToEscape.Add(">", "&gt;");

    string tmp = rawText;

    foreach (string x in xmlCharactersToEscape.Keys)
    {
        if (tmp.Contains(x))
        {
            tmp = tmp.Replace(x, xmlCharactersToEscape[x]);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

The problem is when I use this method to escape the reserved XML characters I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException`. When I do not use this method, the program completes normally.

Can anyone see why this method would cause the program to run out of memory?

Comment: you are replacing `&` with more `&`. You are going to need to do an inline string replacement without using `string.Replace`.

Comment: See [`HttpUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-5.00) if you _have to_, or use `CDATA` instead?

Comment: @Andy Not really sure what you are meaning. The entity replacement for the `&` character is `&amp;`. `string.Replace` should work just fine.

Comment: I would look in to debugging this code. set a break point, step through and watch each variable carefully.